# Guest linux in Virtualbox cannot run KVM inside it, what is best alternative?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, virtualbox, kvm

My setup

HOST: Win 8.1

Guest: Lubuntu 14.04

I develop my apps in my guest

I read here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/328748/how-to-enable-nested-virtualization-in-ubuntu

that you cannot use the android sdk emulation in a virtualized linux, at least not under virtualbox.

Now I can change to vmware workspace. But I like virtualbox better. And I am afraid to break my system.

Is there a way I can, say, install android emulation on my host (windows 8.1) and say, share the android projects in the virtualbox shared folder. Then just run the tests on the shared folder from my host?

Note downloading and installing the android sdk for windows will take me at least 6 hours.

Comment: i doubt that is what I am looking for. I am developping in my box. Do we have a misunderstanding? I edited my question. Those downvoting and close voting: feel free to explain what is wrong with the question.

Comment: i decided to develop straight on the device (e.g. direclty work on my android phone)

Answer (score 0):

According to your topics name, Running VM and install KVM on gust-VM, still doesn't work normally. Because KVM usually makes the Linux kernel as a Hypervisor. If you need to use KVM I think you have to change the guest-vm's virtualization technique. I will try to look for this.